# How to change the variable type for values inside nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, nested-lists

I want to change the variable types of strings whenever possible. ('6' will be converted to 6, '7.8' will be converted to 7.8, 'true' will be converted to True, and 'null' or an empty string will be converted to None)

Here is my code so far:

```
def change_variable_type(variables: List[List[str]]) -> None:
   for sublist in variables: #Access elements inside nested list
      for element in sublist:
         if element.isnumeric(): #Checks if it's a number and converts to a float
            element = float(element)

            if element == int(element): #Checks if it can be an int, and converts if it can
               element = int(element)

         elif element.lower() == 'false': #Checks if it can be False, and converts if it can
            element = False

         elif element.lower() == 'true': #Checks if it can be True, and converts if it can
            element = True

         elif element == 'null' or element == '': #Checks if it can be None, and converts if it can
            element = None

variables_to_convert = [['abc', '123', '123.4', 'true', 'False', '']]
change_variable_type(variables_to_convert)
```

After the code is run, variables_to_convert should be [['abc', 123, 123.4, True, False, None]], however, I just get the original value again. Am I missing something that even a beginner can see or is this some logical error?

PS I apologize to anyone who thinks my code is messy or unorganized. This is just a small function I had to make and so I didn't spend much time on making it look good. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to assign the value back into the list, e.g. `for idx, elem in enumerate(l): l[idx] = int(elem)`. P.S. You can use `eval()` if you trust the contents of the list.

Comment: @Rizhiy `ast.literal_eval` would be better, but neither will handle converting, say, `'null'` to `None`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In loops, variables do not directly refer to lists, so to change any value you need to refer to the original list by index, for this you can use `enumerate`

```py
from typing import List


def change_variable_type(variables: List[List[str]]) -> None:
    for sublist in variables:
        for index, element in enumerate(sublist):
            if element:
                if element.isnumeric():
                    sublist[index] = int(element)
                elif element.replace('.', '').isnumeric():
                    sublist[index] = float(element)
                elif element.lower() == 'true':
                    sublist[index] = True
                elif element.lower() == 'false':
                    sublist[index] = False
            else:
                sublist[index] = None
    return variables


variables_to_convert = [['abc', '123', '123.4', 'true', 'False', '']]
change_variable_type(variables_to_convert)
print(variables_to_convert)
```

outp:

```py
[['abc', 123, 123.4, True, False, None]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reassign variables back into the sublists:

```py
def change_type(element):
     if element.isnumeric(): #Checks if it's a number and converts to a float
        element = float(element)

        if element == int(element): #Checks if it can be an int, and converts if it can
           element = int(element)
        return element

     elif element.lower() == 'false': #Checks if it can be False, and converts if it can
        return False

     elif element.lower() == 'true': #Checks if it can be True, and converts if it can
        return True

     elif element == 'null' or element == '': #Checks if it can be None, and converts if it can
        return None
     return element
    
def change_variable_type(variables):
    for sublist in variables:
        for index, element in enumerate(sublist):
            sublist[index] = change_type(element)

variables_to_convert = [['abc', '123', '123.4', 'true', 'False', '']]
change_variable_type(variables_to_convert)
print(variables_to_convert)
```

Output as requested